# How to prevent updating of an assignment

Tags: dynamic

I have the code you see below:

```
For[ni = 1, ni < 3, ni++,
  ALLB[[ni, 1]] = LB[[1, 1]];];
```

This code is written in a main notebook, and I have another sub notebook, which is called in this loop and evaluates `LB[[1, 1]]` two times. Then `LB[[1, 1]]` will have different values for `ni = 1` and `ni = 2`. Lets say `LB[[1, 1]]` is 5 in the first loop (`ni = 1`) and it is 6 in the second loop (`ni = 2`). I want an answer like `ALLB[[1, 1]] = 5` and `ALLB[[2, 1]] = 6`, but since the dynamic update prevents this from happening, the code gives `ALLB[[1, 1]] = ALLB[[2, 1]] = 6`, which is updated recently as 6.

How could I fix this problem?

Comment: I suppose there's an option to seperate the calculation between notebooks? Or you may simply lauch multiple Mathematica main program.

Comment: Wjx could you be more clear ?

Comment: "Dynamic updating" in *Mathematica* refers to the part of the system that implements the functionality of the command `Dynamic[]`. How are using `Dynamic[]`? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: The loop you've written above doesn't seem to call a sub-notebook at all -- how is that done? How do you know that the value `LB[[1, 1]]` is being changed during each iteration? (Obviously the loop as written is going to execute completely before anything else is done, so `LB` will not change any of its values during the execution of the loop.)

Comment: @MichaelE2, I cut some parts of the code to explain the problem more clear but the code calling a sub notebook is like;

Comment: @MichaelE2 p = 2;
U = ( {
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5}
   } );
ALLB = ConstantArray[0, {11, p + 1}];
docpath = 
  ToFileName[{"C:", "Users", "AHMETHASIM", "Desktop", "AKADEMİK", 
    "YÜKSEK LİSANS", "FEM II"}, "MATHEMATICA"];
For[ni = 1, ni <3, ni++,
  nbLB = NotebookOpen[ToFileName[docpath, "Local_B_spline_Basis3.nb"]];
  SelectionMove[nbLB, All, Notebook];
  SelectionEvaluate[nbLB];
   ALLB[[ni,1]] = LB[[1, 1]];
  NotebookClose[nbLB];
  ];
ALLB